# How to find all hard-coded colors in SCSS?

Tags: css, colors, sass, color-scheme

I'm converting ugly legacy CSS into SCSS (See [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).)

I want to take advantage of its support of variables and create one file where I manage my entire color scheme, just like Twitter's Bootstrap does it (see [the variables file of the SCSS version of Bootstrap](https://github.com/jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap/blob/master/lib/_variables.scss)).

In the old CSS (dozens of files), colors are written in inconsistent ways such as:

- `#fff`
- `#FFF`
- `#FFFFFF`
- `white`

And there are *lots* of colors.

Can you think of an approach (preferably automated and simple) to help identify (and maybe even replace) all of those hard-coded values with my appropriate variables, which look like `$colorGrayDark`?

Comment: If you are on linux system you can use `grep -nr "color" path\to\all-files/` and then do same for background-color. or use some better search term. And If you sublime you can use find->'find in files' in files. than replace them with variable. and If you have some dark or light color than use one variable and use `darken()` and `lighten()` functions in scss.

Comment: This won't find "background" or "border" properties that have background-color or border-color specified in the same line (without the "-color" part).

Comment: normally every editor has a search and replace function

Comment: In my personal experience, trying to figure out an appropriate regex to catch everything is infinitely slower than performing a manual search and replace.  Color keywords must be handled with care, unless you know that none of your classes or ids contain those words.  Prefixes that are guaranteed to match non-keyword colors:  `rgb(`, `rgba(`, `: #`, etc.

Comment: @Ryan If I have to find something like this. I will break it in parts. because in one time It will be lenghty. So first I will search for "color" keyword. than use "background" and than same for "border". And think all other possibilities and search them individually. I think this ways is easier to find and replace.